# How do you run Pokemon Omicron/Zeta?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-zeta-omicron

Pokemon Omicron and Zeta were released in beta recently. See [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemonzetaomicron/comments/1mbfh9/modpost_zetaomicron_beta_v100/).

I downloaded the game, unzipped everything and double clicked the .exe but the window pops up for half a second and crashes. I have downloaded from multiple places and tried both omicron and zeta and they both yield the same result.

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Edit: Here is the inside of the folders

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Hmm.  I can't seem to find any specific requirements, but it was made using RPG Maker XP.  I can run it on Windows 7 64-bit with no issue.  What's your OS and system specs?

Comment: @fbueckert Added that to my question. If you need more info let me know

Comment: A patch just came out, from what I can tell.  No guarantees it'll help, but it might be worth a shot.  Out of curiosity, do you have the .NET Framework installed?  And what versions?  I don't think that's the problem, but it might be.

Comment: I have a lot of Steam games and it seems to install that a lot for the games. How can I check what version I have?

Comment: I tried all the patches and it didn't help

Comment: I also asked this question on the Reddit page. I'm new to Reddit so I'm not entirely sure but I don't think anyone has replied to it.

Comment: Are you sure that it downloaded correctly?

Comment: @Ullallulloo I downloaded it multiple times from every source on the page and none of them worked. The ones that "thesuzerain" posted, who is the person who made the post, those i couldn't even open with 7-zip or WinRar

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big is your zip file?  My Zeta download was 400MB.

Comment: I tried it as well (on same OS) and was able to run it. Can you provide a screenshot of what the inside of your folder looks like?

Comment: @fbueckert 629 MB with the patches

Comment: Hmm. That seems big enough to ensure you got a full download. No errors while unzipping? Any chance you might be able to check your Event Viewer right after a crash? No guarantees, but might give you a clue what the problem could be.

Comment: @fbueckert How would I check that?

Comment: @Guy Added images to my question

Comment: In Control Panel, you want to to System and Security, and one of the choices should be "View Event Logs".  Then you can take a look under the Application logs, or maybe something will show up in System.  You'd specifically be looking for Errors, so hopefully something shows up in one of those two places.

Comment: @fbueckert All I could find in the system area were 7 warnings that processors had slowed down. Where would I look in the application logs?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what it would be under in the Application logs.  Try to find some Error ones, and see if there are any details about game.exe in it.  That might give us a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed .Net 4.0 and 4.5, then use an archive program other than the standard Windows one.  I suggest 7zip 'cause it's free and works.  The Windows extractor can cause issues with unzipping.  I had the same problem.  When I unzipped with 7zip, the exe launched properly.

Comment: +1, I also had problems with the zip file. In my case, I used WinRAR (similar to 7-zip, but its a full-featured trial if you don't purchase it)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your graphics driver, you'll be able to do different things, but you'll need to know what graphics driver you have first. To find your graphics driver, search "device manager" in the start menu and open the first one. Go under Display adapters, and copy what's under Display adapters into google, along with "OpenGL support", so it should look like "(your graphics driver) OpenGL support". Find whichever looks best, and see if it has OpenGL support above 2.0.

If it does, then try to update your graphics driver (in device manager select your graphics driver, right click, "Update Driver Software")

Otherwise, you either need a different computer, or you need a new graphics driver with higher OpenGL support.

I had this problem with Amnesia: The Dark Descent on my other laptop, because it had an Intel(4) Chipset Family graphics card, with minimal OpenGL support.